# Adding files in directory to an array

Tags: node.js, json

I am really new to node.js. I need to read .json files from a directory and then add them to an array and return it. I am able to read each file separately by passing the address:

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("./fashion/customer.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error reading file from disk:", err);
    return;
  }
  try {
    const customer = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    console.log("Customer address is:", customer.address); // => "Customer address is: Infinity Loop Drive"
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error parsing JSON string:", err);
  }
});
```

But the same fashion folder has multiple json files. I want to add these files to an array and then return it. I tried using readdirSync but that just returned the file names. Is it possible to add json files to an array and return it?

Basically I require an array of this format:

```
Array[{contents of json file1}, {contents of json file2}, .....]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to your question:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const jsonFolder = './fashion'
var customerDataArray = []
fs.readdirSync(jsonFolder).forEach(file => {
    let fileData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonFolder+'/'+file))
    customerDataArray.push(fileData)
});
console.log(customerDataArray)
```

readdirSync returns an array with all the file names or objects in the directory. You can use forEach to iterate through every item in the array, which will be the file names in this scenario. To read the contents of each file, use readFileSync and specify the path to the file as the name of the directory plus the name of the file. The data is returned as a buffer and needs to be parsed using JSON.parse(), and then it is pushed to the customerDataArray.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Hey it works! Thanks a ton. I did something very similar to what you did, but I had trouble pushing it into the array. Thanks for your help!